# Android application company ID uniqueness

Tags: android, google-play

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id
This document states:

> This ID uniquely identifies your app on the device and in Google Play Store.

Imagine I have an application with id `com.acme.timetracker`. Is it possible or legal for some other company to publish application with my company prefix `com.acme` on the PlayStore? For example `com.acme.timetrackerbold` or `com.acme.timetracker.bold`?

Answer (score 1):

Legal questions are not the scope of Stackoverflow. But from a technical standpoint it is possible for a third party to publish an application with `com.acme` as their package id.

Comment: The only [outright limited id](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart) are those starting with com.example, com.google and com.android. As for legality, it's more about contracts. Google requires developers using a depiction of a trademarked brand to prove they're licensed to do that or face delisting. I'd guess using a branded application id will trigger the same requirement.

Comment: @Martheen That's interesting. I didn't know there is a list of restricted ids. But it makes sense.